# Test password quality with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

Running this script in powershell the `passwords.txt` file containing the default password that is being used for accounts.
But when I run it outputs the quality report but with no numbers.
Also once the script is put through it asks for a filter which I input: `samAccountName -like '*,OU=Mgmt,DC=balrok,DC=edu'`

```
$Passwords = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\passwords.txt
Get-ADUser | Test-PasswordQuality
```

Note: The [`Test-PasswordQuality`](https://github.com/MichaelGrafnetter/DSInternals/blob/master/Documentation/PowerShell/Test-PasswordQuality.md) cmdlet is part of the third-party [`DSInternals` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DSInternals/).

Comment: A filter like `samAccountName -like '*,OU=Mgmt,DC=balrok,DC=edu'` will not bring any results unless you have users which's samAccountName are actually a DistinguishedName which I personally not see how it could be possible

Comment: Im trying to get all the accounts with default passwords even using names the output is blank

Comment: I don't know - I think that testing the password quality is completely invalidated by the password being stored in a text file.